# Need workaround for invalid getBoundingClientRect() of span in IE6 and IE7 in RTL mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, right-to-left

I'm looking for a workaround for a following problem:

When I try to use `getBoundingClientRect()` for a span with a border `<span id="hello_id" style="border-bottom:dotted 1px">helo</span>` when the document is in RTL mode I get invalid values.

The following code shows an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_rectangle()
{
    var el = document.getElementById('hello_id');
    var rec = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    alert('Left:' + rec.left + ' Right:' + rec.right);
}
setTimeout(show_rectangle,2000);
</script>
</head>
<body style="direction:rtl">
<p id='xxx' style="text-align:center"><span id="hello_id" style="border-bottom:dotted 1px">hello</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The alert is shown "Left:-621 Right:-593", in both IE6 and IE7

When I remove "direction:rtl" from Body's style or style attribute from the span I get reasonable positive values.

How can I workaround this issue: i.e. how can I create a span with border, in rtl document and have correct bounding rectange? Or maybe generate a border without this property?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to put one span inside other, give border style to internal one and measure an external:

```
<p id='xxx' style="text-align:center"><span id="hello_id" ><span style="border-bottom:dotted 1px">hello</span></span></p>
```

Than it works.